# How to define std::tuple<...> with number of arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I need to interface with code that uses (misuses) tuples on the form:

```cpp
using Tuple = std::tuple<double, double, double, double, int, int, int, int>; // etc..
```

I wonder if there is a way to define this tuples with templates instead in the form:

```cpp
using Tuple = SomeType<4, double, 4, int>::Type; // expands to the above tuple
```

And specify the number of arguments instead of specify each type.

I would prefer to only use std libs, but boost is accepted. And I need it to work with c++14. It is easy to do with macros, but I already have a macro solution, and I do not like having macros in the code for this kind of code.

The tuple above is a small example. In reality the tuples is much larger, contains many more types and more of each type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not aware of some `std` facility that does what you want directly.

The tricky part is to have a variadic template with mixed non-type and type parameters. The issue can be avoided by using a helper:

```
template <typename T,size_t reps>
struct repeated_type {
    using type = T;
    static const size_t N = reps;
};
```

Usage can look like this:

```
int main() {
    using two_ints = repeated_type<int,2>;
    using three_doubles = repeated_type<double,3>;
    using my_tuple = n_tuple<two_ints,three_doubles>;
    static_assert(std::is_same<
                         std::tuple<int,int,double,double,double>,
                         my_tuple
                  >::value);
}
```

Using a [`std::index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) we can get a `std::tuple<T,T,T,...T>` via [`std::make_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple)

```
template <typename T,std::size_t...n>
auto n_tuple_impl(std::index_sequence<n...>){ 
    return std::make_tuple( (n,T{})...); 
}

template <typename repT>
using n_tuple_single = decltype( 
                           n_tuple_impl<typename repT::type>(
                               std::make_index_sequence<repT::N>() 
                           )
                       );
```

Concatenetating several of them can be done via [`std::tuple_cat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat):

```
template <typename...repT>
using n_tuple = decltype( 
                    std::tuple_cat( 
                        ( n_tuple_single<repT>() )... 
                    ) 
                );
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jvvf4K).

In two places I require default construction. If needed this could be circumvented via `std::declval`. No instances are actually created.

For the interested reader, [here](https://godbolt.org/z/bTxMrz) is a rather messy C++11 implementation that is based on recursion instead of `std::index_sequence` and fold expressions to achieve the same.

Comment: Wow magic! Lots of templated classes, as expected, but it actually works. Thanks!

Comment: @Lasersköld don't miss the disclaimer. This was just my first attempt at getting it to work somehow. I might update the answer later with something that uses less recursion

Comment: @Lasersköld see update. Down to 3 types, 1 function, and no more recursion ;)

Comment: I realized that `std::make_tuple( (n,T{})...);` could cause a compiler warning. That could easily be fixed with adding (void) like so: `std::make_tuple( ((void)n,T{})...);`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short solution using `Boost.MP11` and can work with any type list holder (e.g. `std::tuple`, `boost::mp11::mp_list`, etc).

```cpp
#include <boost/mp11/algorithm.hpp>

#include <cstddef>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T, std::size_t N, template<class...> class THolder = std::tuple>
struct repeater {
    using type = boost::mp11::mp_repeat_c<THolder<T>, N>;
};

template<class T, std::size_t N>
using repeater_t = typename repeater<T, N>::type;

int main() {
    using expected_t = std::tuple<double, double, double, double, int, int, int, int>;
    using actual_t = boost::mp11::mp_append<repeater_t<double, 4>, repeater_t<int, 4>>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<actual_t, expected_t>);
}
```

Here, we leverage `boost::mp11::mp_repeat_c` to build the type holder holding `N` types of type `T`. The type list we default to is `std::tuple` as requested. Then, at the call site, it's just a matter of appending the tuples together via `boost::mp11::mp_append` to get down to one tuple.

[Wandbox link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YqL8h4d9W5ViyL8g)